# Retrieving Text between specific html tags from a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I browsed through this query that people have earlier asked on this forum. But I could not find my solution. So, I really apologize for the similar kind of question.

My problem is:

I have a text file that contains HTML tags along with the text. I want to retrieve text between specific HTML tags.
After retrieving text from HTML tags, I want to replace that text with a constant string.

For example,

```
"<span class="proflinkWrapper"><span class="proflinkPrefix">+</span><a class="proflink" href="https://xyzlink" id=123456">Donald</a></span>"
```

I want the result as +Donald and then replace with "President"

I need to find and replace the text between this specific tag throughout the file. Text in between these tags is not same but want to replace each text with "President"

Answer (score 0):

You can use web scraping python packages like *BeautifulSoup*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
str = '<span class="proflinkWrapper"><span class="proflinkPrefix">+</span><a class="proflink" href="https://xyzlink" id="123456">Donald</a></span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(str,'lxml')
try:
    span = soup.find("span",{"class": "proflinkWrapper"}).find("span",{"class": "proflinkPrefix"})
    a = soup.find("a",id="123456")
    a.string = a.text.replace(a.text, "president")
    print (soup.prettify())
except:
    print ("Exception")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved it via regex. Your help is really appreciated.